# Convert Array with objects to manipulate

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to manipulate this array and play with parse, push and save data commands. but for some reason is not reading. 
Any help? 
I'm super new to it and just trying to practice.
Should be an array of objects.

```
    var employeeString = [
    { first_name: 'Josh', last_name:'Neil', nationality:'Indian'},
    { first_name: 'Brian', last_name:'Cok', nationality:'Canadian'},
    { first_name: 'Katja', last_name:'Fanta', nationality:'German'} 
];
    var jsonValues = JSON.stringify(employeeString);
    current_values = JSON.parse(jsonValues);

    var nationality = [];
    //console.log (current_values);

    for ( i = 0; i < current_values.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = current_values[i]
        var first_name = currentItem['first_name'];
        var last_name = currentItem['last_name'];

        //push value into array
        nationality.push(currentItem['nationality']);
        if (currentItem == 'first_name' || currentItem == 'last_name') { 
            return id[i+1]; 
        }
    }

        console.log (first_name , last_name);
```

Comment: you need no parse, because you have allready an array.

Comment: Im doing it already, have a look

Comment: please add what you like to get (the final result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the already JSON object.
For example `JSON.parse('[{x:10},{y:20}]');` will return JSON object from the string. This step is required to access the value of x and y, which are in string form as you can see `''` around it. But in your case, you already got a JSON Object you don't need to parse it again.
Further in console.log if you want to print first_name, do not add `''` around it. Here is your working code

```js
var current_values = [
  { first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Neil', Nationality: 'Indian' },
  { first_name: 'Brian', last_name: 'Cok', Nationality: 'Canadian' },
  { first_name: 'Katja', last_name: 'Fanta', Nationality: 'German' }
];

//     current_values = JSON.parse(employeeString);

//     console.log(current_values);

for (i = 0; i < current_values.length; i++) {
  var currentItem = current_values[i]
  var first_name = currentItem['first_name'];
  var last_name = currentItem['last_name'];
  console.log(first_name, last_name);
}
```

Comment: I got until this point now, but only prints the last name! if (currentItem == 'first_name') { 
        //     return obj[i+1];

Comment: currentItem contains the whole object `{ first_name: 'Josh', last_name: 'Neil', Nationality: 'Indian' }`. what condition do you want to meet.

Comment: sum the names on key "first_name" and print all names. same for another keys.

Comment: sorry, I don't get "sum the names", you want to concatenate the names?

Comment: share the out put you want.

Comment: console.log(first_name) should print Josh, Brian, Katja.

Comment: your if condition is wrong. if you want to check that if first_name is there than use `if(currentItem.first_name){console.log(first_name);}`

Comment: names are their but is only print one. can you tell me why?

Comment: your console is outside of for loop

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.parse` method accepts a *string*, but you're giving it an array of objects.

```
var values = JSON.parse("[{'first_name': 'Josh', ...}, ...]");
```

Would work better.

In general, parsing will convert a string to objects.  http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/seuss.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `JSON.parse(employeeString)`, since it is already an object.

---

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is used to create objects from their string representation, e.g. parse the string `'{"prop":42}'` to an actual object with a property `prop` and its value being `42`. Since `employeeString` in your code is already an object, you don't need to `JSON.parse` it again.

BTW, you probably meant this:

```
// notice that this is now an actual string
var employeeString = `[
    { first_name: 'Josh', last_name:'Neil', Nationality:'Indian'},
    { first_name: 'Brian', last_name:'Cok', Nationality:'Canadian'},
    { first_name: 'Katja', last_name:'Fanta', Nationality:'German'} 
]`;
```

Comment: I'm trying to save all datas by "key" and print it. still not working

Comment: Also notice that everything after `return` statement is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The data type for `employeeString` is Array, but `JSON.parse()` is supposed to parse JSON data. So, you can first change `employeeString` into a JSON data before parse it.

Comment: var jsonValues = JSON.stringify(employeeString);
     current_values = JSON.parse(jsonValues); right?

Comment: @paulo.gomes Yes, this is one way to convert a non-JSON data to JSON data in JavaScript.

Comment: @paulo.gomes But you also realise that it doesn't do some useful thing. I mean if you have an array, just iterate it, no need to play with JSON. But if your original data is JSON (actually is string), then you just simply JSON.parse(yourData) and work with it.